# Forcing a background application to terminate in iOS simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

In iOS 4 applications go to the background instead of terminating. For this reason I have to register for:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                      selector:@selector(appWillTerminate:)
                                      name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification
                                      object:[UIApplication sharedApplication]];
```

Instead of UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification.

But what happens if I want to test my UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification. How can I test it in the simulator?

Comment: What you mean go to the background instead of terminating?

Answer (score 8):

If you want to test the reception of such a notification, add following key to your Info.plist file: `Application does not run in background` and set it to YES. The internal name is `<key>UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend</key>`.

This will tell iOS and the simulator, that your application wants to terminate rather than being sent to background when the home button is pressed. In this case, the `UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification` is sent.

For testing, this should suffice.

Hope this helps.